# how to use database in our application means procedure for getting data from database

Tags: sqlite

Hi can anyone give info about how to create database using sqlite and how to insert data into the tables in database and how to retrieve all sqlite based issues. I don't have much idea how to use database in application so can any one tell me the procedure how to do use this and create app.

thanking you

Answer (score 0):

since you don't refer to any programing language specific, i will give some general info in a hope to be helpful.

One easy way to create and manage an SQLite database is the SQLite Manager which is a Firefox add on, with it you can visually create, browse, export databases, create and execute queries and so on. It is free and cross platform, you can check it here: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/

As the home page says, SQLite is a self-contained - serverless database which means you don't have to install a database server. It supports many programing languages, here is some clues how to use it with Python programming language http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html

If you need more details please be more specific about the subject, the goal and the programing language.